# How to prove which asmyptotic notation is valid

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I have a question where I’m given that f(n)= 27n^3 +27n and g(n)= 2n^3 + n^2 and I have to decide if f(n) ∈ O(g(n)), f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n)), or f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n)). I think f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n)) because they would have the same rate of growths, but I’m not sure.

Answer (score 1):

First try to prove that f(n) = O(g(n)), and then prove that f(n) = Ω(g(n)). Then, there's a theorem that says if f(n) = O(g(n)) and f(n) = Ω(g(n)), we can conclude that f(n) = Θ(g(n)).

If you want to prove that directly, you should use the asymptotic definitions:

1) Big-O: prove that constants c and n_0 exist, such that f(n) <= c g(n) for all n >= n_0

2) Big-Ω: prove that constants c and n_0 exist, such that f(n) >= c g(n) for all n >= n_0

3) Big-Θ: prove that constants c_1 and c_2 and n_0 exist, such that c_1 g(n) <= f(n) <= c_2 g(n) for all n >= n_0

Anyways, your guess is right and in that example f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n)).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend learning the simple technique of bounding by following this example:

```
f(n)  = 27n^3 + 27n
     <= 27n^3 + 27n^2
     <= 27(n^3 + n^2)
     <= 27(2n^3 + n^2)
     <= 27g(n)

g(n)  = 2n^3 + n^2
     <= 2n^3 + n^3
      = 3n^3
     <= 27n^3
     <= 27n^3 + 27n
      = f(n)
```